# First and last occurrence of an element in an sorted array

Tags: java, search

I am solving a leetcode problem of finding the first and last occurrence of an element in an sorted array. Since it is a sorted array I'm using binary search. but even though I'm passing the ryt arguments to a method it shows an error actual and formal argument lists differ in length.

Here's my code,

```
class Solution {
    public int searchRange(int[] nums, int target, boolean findStart) {
        int ans = -1;
        int start = 0;
        int end = nums.length - 1;
        while (start <= end) {
            int mid = start + (end - start) / 2;
            if (target < nums[mid]) {
                end = mid - 1;
            } else if (target > nums[mid]) {
                start = mid + 1;
            } else {
                ans = mid;
                if (findStart) {
                    end = mid - 1;
                } else {
                    start = mid + 1;
                }
            }
        }
        return ans;
    }

    public void main(String[] args) {
        int[] nums = {5, 7, 7, 8, 8, 10};
        int target = 8;
        int[] result = search(nums,target);
        System.out.println(result);
    }

    public int[] search(int[] nums, int target) {
        int[] result = {-1, -1};
        int start = searchRange(nums, target, true);
        int end = searchRange(nums, target, false);
        result[0] = start;
        result[1] = end;
        return result;
    }
}

Compile Error
Line 7: error: method searchRange in class Solution cannot be applied to given types; [in __Driver__.java]
      int[] ret = new Solution().searchRange(param_1, param_2);
                                ^
  required: int[],int,boolean
  found:    int[],int
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

Comment: You are trying to call a method that doesn't exist by trying to call `searchRange(int, int)` but the actual method expects 3 parameters: `searchRange(int, int, boolean)`.  If your method expects 3 arguments you need to call it with those 3 arguments. Also: The error message points to specific line in your code, and for some reason you didn't include that line - the line that actually causes the error - into the code of your question. This is quite sub-optimal.

Comment: Off-topic:  This seems to be the page for the problem at LeetCode: https://leetcode.com/problems/find-first-and-last-position-of-element-in-sorted-array/

Comment: Please include all the code in your question.  You provided all the code except the part that caused the error.  Namely the instance of `Solution` invoking `searchRange`.  And main should be declare static if you expect to run this (although that may be a leetcode requriement).

Comment: Or just call `.search(int[],int)` since that may be the intent of the class.

Comment: @WJS That's the problem here. There is no such line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is clear from the error message: the LeetCode framework has code that calls `searchRange` with 2 arguments, while your implementation doesn't have a function with that signature. It has a `searchRange` with a third parameter.

The fix is to rename your `search` function (which *does* have the required parameter list) to `searchRange`. That way you overload `searchRange` so it can be called with both 2 and 3 arguments. The LeetCode code that will test your solution will now find the right function and will be able to call it.

The `main` function should not be part of what you submit to LeetCode: it is not used.

The rest of your code is fine.